# Benefits of Terragrunt DRY configuration over "Native" Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I just learned about Terragrunt. While I see some nice things, that are missing in Terraform, I do not fully understand the real benefit of the DRY configuration aspect (which seems to be the most promoted aspect of Terragrunt).

In all those examples I've seen, the HCL files (e.g. for the various stages) look pretty redundant to me – and basically contain the same information that one would pass within a `module {}` block in plain Terraform.

Can’t you achieve the same thing with roughly the same amount of code by writing a “composition module” in plain Terraform that only instantiates other modules? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Terragrunt too, and initially, I had the same thought.

Have you read https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs#features?

As Terragrunt itself says that it's just a thin layer on top of Terraform to add certain features over TF. A few DRY features that stand out to me:

1. generate remote backend config
2. generate provider config code
3. doesn't need to repeat input variables in a multiple modules design
4. can execute on each child modules as well as all modules at the same time

Perhaps it's clearer if you create the same design using both Terraform module composition and Terragrunt to see the differences.

Comment: I don't see a big difference between my current solution in Terraform, and the same design migrated to Terragrunt. Hence my question here.

Comment: Thinking about it for a little longer, I think the benefit only starts to arise when using Terragrunt to separate your *root* modules into much smaller parts. Then you can reduce redundancy in backend and provider config - as you've already stated.

Maybe Terragrunt is meant to support you in spitting up your root module. Makes sense in combination with its dependency feature.

I guess the Terragrunt documentation is not good at pointing out its benefits...

Comment: Yeah, on the surface, if we just have a big root module for an environment, then using tf module composition vs Terragrunt won't have many differences.

Terragrunt would allow us to use a deep folder structure for multi-cloud, multi-region, and multi-environment to isolate terraform configs and achieve DRY

root/
- cloud/
-- region/
--- env/
---- infra/
----- .terragrunt.hcl
---- app/
----- .terragrunt.hcl
---- etc.
----- .terragrunt.hcl

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that typical design patterns these days are that you're going to have that layer you are referring to as the "composition module" calling a number of underlying modules to do their work.   This is called other things in other worlds - some call them blueprints, terraform cloud calls this your "configuration" but most designs include something along these lines.

What terragrunt allows you to do is to take that "composition module" and instantiate it many times using unique variables each time.   If you haven't made that module very reusable this won't be possible but if it is the pattern is:

1. Terragrunt calls your composition module using unique values from 1 directory.   That calls all of its underlying modules to give you a complete deployment for that directory/workspace/whatever your tool feels like calling it.   And this area gets its own remote state.
2. Terragrunt calls your composition module from another directory using different values.    That again calls all of the underlying modules to give you a complete deployment for a different directory/workspace/whatever you want to call it.   This area also gets its own remote state.

And you could reuse this same composition module 50/100/infinity times in totally unique ways all which don't conflict with each other.

This is a very common design pattern now.   And you can achieve the same effect without terragrunt as well.   It is a nice wrapper that makes it extremely easy though.

There's quite a few other benefits as well, but just in terms of execution context this is how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Native Terraform (and now also [OpenTofu](https://opentofu.org/docs/language/modules/)) supports modules, so support for general code reuse is available with or without Terragrunt. But Terragrunt does provide some additional features that, in certain cases, can help further avoid duplication.

1. For a monorepo with multiple subsystems and/or deployment environments, Terragrunt can eliminate duplication by making provider and backend configuration implicit per deployment.
2. [Include files](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example/tree/master/_envcommon) can be used to avoid duplication of virtually all subsystem boilerplate per environment. If you take full advantage of this, the per-deployment code can be reduced to a couple of include statements and whatever environment-specific parameter overrides you may need.
3. On top of those features, Terragrunt offers a low-code solution for [bootstrapping](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/#create-remote-state-and-locking-resources-automatically) your backend(s), so you can avoid the boilerplate (and/or manual steps) that might otherwise be required for managing that.

Terragrunt has a set of pages introducing these features (with an [example](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example.git)):

- [Keep your Terraform code DRY](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/)
- [Keep your remote state configuration DRY](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/)
- [Keep your Terragrunt Architecture DRY](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terragrunt-architecture-dry/)

---

The indirection required to take full advantage of Terragrunt's DRY features results in a scattered configuration that can be painful to reason about. Someone actually interested in clean, DRY code, may prefer the [workspaces](https://opentofu.org/docs/cli/workspaces/) approach to managing multiple environments.

---

It's worth observing that Terragrunt was conceived at a time when Terraform itself was still in its infancy. As Terraform evolved, some of the original benefits of Terragrunt have become more-or-less obsolete. Nevertheless, if you're adopting the copy-paste-per-environment paradigm, a fully-minimized Terragrunt implementation will likely be moderately more concise than the equivalent in pure Terraform.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-with-terraform-32c7bc5d692) from Terragrunt addressing multiple choice points. Notice that Workspaces gets a slightly better score than Terragrunt for 'Minimize code duplication'. See also, related issue: [What are the pros/cons of using Terragrunt versus Terraform Workspaces when instantiating modules? #92](https://github.com/orgs/gruntwork-io/discussions/92)

Comment: ...Terragrunt is just a [thin wrapper](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) around Terraform so, of course, you could add any Terragrunt feature with _your own_ "thin wrapper" -- which might in be trivial to implement in some cases (e.g. different backends per environment just means you log into a different account when switching workspaces).

Comment: I came across the above blog post when searching for people's experiences managing environments using file system duplication (the Terragrunt way). My experience is the exact opposite of the advantage listed: "Navigating environments and understanding what’s deployed is easy: just browse the file system." I find that duplicated code becomes divergent and unwieldy (and scattered). Plus, what guarantee do you have that the code actually matches the deployment? To me, environments are much easier to navigate with workspaces and (Git) version tagging. And, when in doubt, just run `terraform plan`.

Comment: This is tangential but I've been looking for a discussion about Terragrunt `mock_outputs` and I finally found this (because I had a related problem): [Terragrunt fails to get outputs of dependency #1330](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1330), linked from [Terragrunt doesn't get outputs from a imported source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435792/terragrunt-doesnt-get-outputs-from-a-imported-source)

Comment: Once you start using [dependency blocks](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#dependency) for [module composition](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#passing-outputs-between-modules), it's no longer accurate to call Terragrunt a _thin wrapper_. At that point, you're writing _extra_ code in Terragrunt's unique vocabulary and Terragrunt replaces Terraform's dependency management with it's own, less capable (and less DRY), implementation. See: "Unapplied dependency and mock outputs"